# pdf read pages to BitmapData in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, pdf, binary, bitmapdata

I’m starting a project in flash AS3 and my objective is to load any pdf file into my flash project and convert all its pages to BitmapData...

I am familiar with byteArray and I know I must access the pdf in binary level but I don’t know where to start and how to start.

I was hoping if you could give me some insight? Maybe a suggestion to an already library that is doing a similar work?

Any idea os appreciated just to get me started...

Comment: First of all, you'd need some way to render the PDF.

Comment: yeah, exactly... but building my own classes for that may take a lot of time! any one has ever built a library reference for that?

Comment: try porting XPDF library into AS3... :)

Comment: XPDF is written in C++ how can I use that with AS3? any ideas?

Comment: No need to mess with C/C++. Use http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can get any PDF renderer written on C/C++ and convert it using Alchemy to flash library.
[Read this topic](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/553430)